# Запрос с параметрами

Tags: sql

Есть некий запрос с параметрами, но не все параметры всегда присутствуют и результат запроса - пустая таблица, так как параметр равен пустому значению и записей с пустым значением нет в таблице. Как сделать, чтобы если параметра нет, то запрос исполнялся бы без него.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM [Table]
WHERE (([Field1] = @param1) OR @param1 IS NULL) AND
      (([Field2] = @param2) OR @param2 IS NULL)
```

и т.д.

Comment: Сам пользуюсь такой уловкой. Только `@param1 IS NULL` лучше поставить перед `[Field1] = @param1`. Чтобы оптимизатор в случае `@param1 IS NULL = FALSE` исключил обработку `[Field1] = @param1`.

Comment: Не поможет. Сервер по порядку а) компилирует запрос, бэ) принимает параметры вэ) выполняет запрос
так вот, компиляция запроса даст план, где будет сначала выполняться сканирование по [Field1] = @param1, а потом для каждой строки вычислять @param1 IS NULL. Правильное решение в этом случае - применить хинт RECOMPILE. Тогда сервер сначала упростит условие, а потом составит новый план выполнения
SELECT * FROM [Table] WHERE .. OPTION (RECOMPILE)

Comment: Уточняю, что я веду речь об MS SQL.